# Ubuntu 22.04 Startup disk creator does not work for older BIOS machines

Tags: boot, startup, disk, 22.04

I've tried using startup disk creator with 2 different Dell Optiplex 990s. One is running 22.04 and the other 20.04. The 22.04 machine upgraded from 20.04. They will not boot from the usb drive at all in UEFI mode and although they get to grub in legacy mode, they crash with a message of zstd corrupt data. This behavior is the same with drives flashed with unetbootin, etcher and dd. I have been able to get the iso to work using Rufus and checking the box for fixes for older bios machines. Unfortunately, this requires a Windows machine to create the usb bott. I have also tried burning a dvd, but it never finshes the boot process. It just thrashes the dvd drive forever. Is there a Linux way of making usb drives that boot older legacy mode machines? older Ubuntu distros did not have this problem.

Comment: You should verify the ISO before anything else. If corrupt then no matter what tool you use the result will be the same. And if the PC has UEFI options then it isn't that old to require the additional settings provided by Rufus. But you should update UEFI before trying to install anything. And, of course, although Legacy is possible it shouldn't be used for any 10 years old or newer PC, it should ONLY be used for old BIOS based computers, yours isn't.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the problem was not the "startup disk creator" utility or the iso file. The culprit was the fact that I was using an older USB 2 thumb drive that was reading very slowly. Although its image would verify in etcher and it would actually run (agonizingly slowly) in the "test disk" qemu session, there must have been a timing problem when booting using the Optiplex 990. I've since verified that using either Rufus (which makes a fat32 partition rather than joliet) or the startup disk creator works fine if I use a faster USB 3 drive. So there's no problem with the disk creator, but the boot process in the Ubuntu distro is a wee bit intolerant of drive reading speed.

The problem with trying to switch to uefi with the Optiplex 990 is that I can't get any usb thumb drive to boot in that mode. So I've given up trying.

Update: Spoke too soon on the booting in uefi issue. The new thumb drive will boot in uefi mode and I've been able to install jammy on an ssd with gpt in uefi mode. You have to hold your nose in a certain way to get the old Dell to boot the rith efi file, but it seems to work. This is great!

Comment: Such old computers may have more or less experimental UEFI systems, so I would not spend too much time to make them boot in UEFI mode. It is the opposite with new computers, they are focused on UEFI mode, and the CSM to emulate legacy mode might be flaky. In the near future we will probably see several UEFI-only computers.

Comment: Try with [mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and the `dus-iso2usb` method. This method is made in order to make some of the problematic computers boot (in UEFI mode as well as in legacy mode). Some old computers (for example old HP) need an MSDOS partition table and a boot flag to boot in legacy mode. But I don't think Dells are affected by that issue. I have an even older Optiplex 760 with core2duo for testing, and it works with the current versions. I have tested Lubuntu 22.04 LTS and the preinstalled kinetic server (kinetic will be released as 22.10 in October).